# Catch events on ONOS REST API Applications

Tags: java, rest, events, sdn, onos

I'm using `ONOS` as my `SDN` Controller, `REST` in `NB` and `Netconf` in `SB`.
I can send data over these layers, catch response and analyse them.
Now, the question is how to receive events in `REST API` APPs.
I mean there be no need for the APPs to send request and analyse the response, if something happens it automatically be sent to `NB` APPs.
What can I do to implement this structure?
And is it possible for `REST` Applications to receive events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer.

`ONOS` has an integration named `kafka` which can send events to a `consumer`.
I also added a `kafka producer` as a module to `ONOS` core that can send other events which are not supported by `ONOS` right now.

till this day `ONOS` supports ***LINK*** and ***DEVICE*** events.

for more information:

https://wiki.onosproject.org/display/ONOS/Kafka+Integration

and:

http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

good luck!